# Why does google search page source results crash webdriver?

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, webdriver, rselenium

**Using Linux why does google search results page source for anything crash my browser?**

When I read google href results from any search using the findElements it works just fine, but when I use remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] (to parse using rvest instead) IT CRASHES MY WEBDRIVER ALWAYS.

**The example below is reproducible to get the error using a linux google compute engine VM:**

Reproduce webdriver:

```
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
library(httr)

randsleep <- function(low=1,high=2){
  Sys.sleep(sample(seq(low,high,by=0.001),1))
}

system("sudo kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:4444)")
system("sudo kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:4445)")
eCaps <- list(chromeOptions = list(
  args = c('--headless', '--disable-gpu', '--window-size=1280,800')
))
randsleep()
rD <- rsDriver(port=4445L, extraCapabilities = eCaps, browser=c("chrome"), chromever = "76.0.3809.68")
randsleep()
remDr <- rD$client
```

Reproduce search:

```
searchstring <- "dogs"
remDr$navigate("https://www.google.com")
randsleep(4,6)
googsearch <- remDr$findElement(using='xpath','//input[@name="q"]')
randsleep(2,3)
googsearch$sendKeysToElement(list(searchstring))
randsleep(2,3)
googsearch$submitElement()
randsleep(10,15)
```

WORKS FINE:

```
googres <- remDr$findElements(using='xpath','//div[@class="r"]/a')
reslinks <- sapply(seq_along(googres),FUN=function(x){googres[[x]]$getElementAttribute("href")})
```

CRASHES THE WEBDRIVER:

```
ps1 <- remDr$getPageSource()
#ERROR:
Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Failed to connect to localhost port 4445: Connection refused
```

Comment: Worked fine for me